# What is the best way to store my own text records into the future?

Tags: preservation

Here is what I want to do:

1. Record my memories somewhere they will last for the next 200 years (or as long as possible), so my posterity etc can get at them
2. I'd prefer to use a digital format so they can be easily distributed and accessed (i.e., not just write in a book by hand because that's very difficult to make copies; only the person with the physical copy has access)

A [FamilySearch Blog post](https://familysearch.org/blog/en/saving-family-history-securely-cloud/) suggested using some type of cloud storage. That's pretty good, but what guarantee do I have the company that provides the service will exist in 200 years? Or won't change their policy and refuse access? Or get hacked. (I suppose it's also possible the cloud servers could be destroyed too). Eg, I was using an iPhone app to record my stories for a while, and then the app got removed from the App Store after a few years (I managed to get a database dump of the data, but now it just sits on my computer).

I thought using [FamilySearch's "Memories"](https://familysearch.org/developers/docs/guides/memories) would be a good fit: if it works well enough for storing my ancestors stories, it should work well enough for my own. Plus FamilySearch actually developed from the Utah Genealogical Society so it's been around for over a hundred years. 
Plus, they have the whole granite mountain vault for storing records right? (Not sure if FamilySearch Memories are backed up there though).
So is using FamilySearch Memories the best chance at preserving my memories for the next 200+ years? Or what might be better?

Comment: I also discovered these details about family search's digital records preservation policies: https://familysearch.org/archives/services/#preservation which tends to supports the idea of using family search memories

Comment: Also I found this 4 year old article suggesting to use M-Discs: https://familysearch.org/blog/en/solutions-archival-storage-media-challenges/, but it also admits it's up to you to keep the discs safe, and ensure you update to other storage devices and file formats once blue rays and our current software becomes obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of your best bets is to save it as a PDF or another very common file format, and then both upload it to a cloud provider and send copies of it to a couple of relatives who seem interested. Having multiple relatives with copies will help it survive the longest.

(You can only be responsible for preserving it during your lifetime; after that, your younger relatives are going to be responsible for it.)

Comment: Donate a copy to your local historical museum. I find letters and photos from relatives frequently at our local historical society; it helps that my family has lived here for a long time.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take our 2-minute [Tour] that introduces you to the site which works differently (and better :-) than a discussion forum etc.  I hope you will enjoy answering, asking and reading the Q&As here.